# Facebook SDK / Where to store the long-lived access token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, architecture, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use the Facebook Javascript SDK logging in User by retrieving a short-lived access token.
This short-lived access token is immediately sent to my app server, in order to get a long-lived one from it.

I think about 2 ways to deal with this token:

- Storing it as a `User`'s field (`User` being an Entity dealing only with authentication mechanism, not the same as `UserProfile`) in the database, so that it can only be associated to its particular user.
- Do not store it in the database but replace the Facebook cookie containing the initial short-lived access token by the long-lived one.

I guess the first way is handy, since I wouldn't need to care about any cookies at all.

What would be the common good practice?

Comment: Did you got any answers about this so far? I'm with the exact same question and looking for answers.

Comment: I store the token in database, far more secure especially if I encrypt it with SHA-256. Would be risky to trust a cookie...

Comment: Nice! How do you treat the case where the access token expires?

Comment: @WilliamLepinski Every time the user logs in into my app, I generate another long-lived token from the short one (at server side) and update it in database. So that, I never have to handle any expiration case.

Comment: Cool!. That's exactly what i'm doing right now.